# Unable to follow the last part of an algebra proof

Tags: algebra-precalculus, recreational-mathematics, integers, irrational-numbers

I am currently going through the book [Topics in Algebra and Analysis](https://www.google.co.in/books/edition/Topics_in_Algebra_and_Analysis/C2GYBgAAQBAJ?hl=en&gbpv=1&printsec=frontcover), and am unable to understand the solution to the following problem on page 7,

**Exercise 1.5.** Prove that there are an infinite no. of pairs of irrational no.s $a,b$ such that $a + b = ab$ is an integer number.

[image: Solution]

I understood the first half of the solution where they found the expressions for $a$ and $b$, but I was unable to understand their proof for the irrationality of the discriminant.
Why exactly do we have to take $n \geq 5$, and how do we get the inequality immediately after that? I feel like they skipped a few 'obvious' steps which aren't obvious to me. Besides, is there a simpler way to prove this? I have searched elsewhere but found nothing, so I would be grateful if anyone could help me understand this proof.

Comment: They've got all the steps, except maybe the following: as they proved $(n-3)^2<n^2-4n<(n-2)^2$ for $n\ge 5$, this implies that $n-3<\sqrt{n^2-4n}<n-2$ i.e. $\sqrt{n^2-4n}$ is strictly between two consecutive integers. Thus, it is not an integer. OTOH it can be easily proven that a square root of an integer is either an integer or an irrational number, so $\sqrt{n^2-4n}$, not being an integer, must be irrational.

Comment: ("Easily be proven": this is because a square of a rational number $p/q$ which is not integer cannot be an integer. Namely, take $p,q$ to be coprime, then $q>1$ and $p^2,q^2$ are coprime and so the square is $p^2/q^2$ in the reduced form, with $q^2>1$ - is not an integer.)

Comment: My guess is that, as $n^2-4n$ can be completed to a square, i.e. $n^2-4n=n^2-4n+4-4=(n-2)^2-4$, then you easily see that $n^2-4n<(n-2)^2$, and you have a half of the inequality already! All they did was to find under which circumstances $n^2-4n$ is greater than the previous square number $(n-3)^2$.

Comment: Ah, sorry for the late reply, but I think I get it now. So they wanted to prove that the square root of integer $n² - 4n$ lies between two consecutive integers, and that implies that $\sqrt{n² - 4n}$ is irrational. So they completed the square for $n² - 4n$ and found $n² - 4n \lt (n - 2)²$ and then found by trial and error that for $n \geq 5$, $(n - 3)² \lt n² - 4n$.

Comment: Thanks a lot, I think I understand it now

Comment: "Trial and error" ... or just by solving $(n-3)^2\lt n^2-4n$ as a (linear, as it will turn out) inequality.